# Cumulative Flow Data for Unscheduled Items?

Tags: rally

I understand how to get cumulative flow data on releases with the ReleaseCumulativeFlowData object - however this requires a ReleaseObjectID. I am looking for a way to get the same data for all the items that are not scheduled in a release, and it does not appear that I can query for where the ReleaseObjectID is null.

**Is there any way using CumulativeFlow data to get the number of story points for unscheduled stories on a given day- or is my best bet to either parse the revision history logs using the 1.x API, or use the Lookback API?**

Basically, what I am trying to get to is to be able to represent how the total scope of a project has changed over time, including items that are scheduled, as well as items that are estimated in the backlog but are not yet scheduled.  - As far as I can tell, there is not an out-of-the-box way to get this information (without revision logs or diving into learning the Lookback API right now), but I am crossing my fingers that I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend learning the Lookback API, as this is exactly the sort of question it was designed to answer.

You can find the docs here: https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/

For example, if you say:

```
find:{
    _ProjectHierarchy:279050021,
    _TypeHierarchy: "HierarchicalRequirement",
    Children: null,
    ScheduleState:{$lt:"In-Progress"},
    __At:"current"
},
fields:["ObjectID", "Name", "PlanEstimate"]
```

You're looking for snapshots for items under the project with OID 279050021, that are Stories (HierarchicalRequirements), with no children (so are leaf stories), that are in a schedule state earlier than "In-Progress" and we should look for snapshots that are valid today ("current"), but you could have put any [ISO 8601 date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) in there as a string.  The fields parameter then specifies which fields of the snapshots to return.  While you're learning what's there, it can be helpful to use fields=true and use this Chrome plugin for pretty-printing the JSON response: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview-and-jsonlint-for/mfjgkleajnieiaonjglfmanlmibchpam  However, you should specify the exact list of fields you want when going to production, since fields=true is limited to 200 results.

As a full URL this looks like:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/41529001/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={_ProjectHierarchy:279050021, _TypeHierarchy: "HierarchicalRequirement", Children: null, ScheduleState:{$lt:"In-Progress"}, __At:"current"}&fields=["ObjectID", "Name", "PlanEstimate"]
```

But make sure to swap in your own workspace OID (for 41529001) and project OID (for 279050021) or the above URL won't work for you.

Comment: Thanks! - I suspected that the best way to do this was using the Lookback API, but I was hoping there was something I was missing in the current API.